# gperftools/tcmalloc 2.8 - running out of memory

Tags: linux, out-of-memory, centos6.5, tcmalloc, gperftools

We are migrating from gperftools/tcmalloc 2.0 to 2.8. But some of our test cases fail with "out of memory" error. We use Cent OS 6.5.
This happens with a posix_memalign() call requesting for 32536008 bytes with 64bit alignment.
I didn't use any specific options with configure while installing gperftools.
Has anyone faced something similar with tcmalloc 2.8 ?
Thanks,
Pramod

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by bug. Bug is fixed in recently released 2.8.1 version. Please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. Version 2.8.1 seems to work fine.